# How to clear CUPS spool automatically?

Tags: macos, printing, cups

When printing to HP printer, I noticed that all printed files are saved to `/var/spool/cups`.

Is it possible to avoid this from a privacy perspective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the job files can be done with the cancel(1) command.

```
$ cancel -a -x
```

will remove all job files for the current user.

If you want CUPS to not save them at all, the `PreserveJobFiles` directive can be added to cupsd.conf as described here:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-372/cups/doc/help/ref-cupsd-conf.html.in

(somewhere along the line Apple has stopped including this documentation file at opensource.apple.com, this seems to be the last version the file exists for, although CUPS itself is a higher version now)

Comment: Hey Marc, brilliant answer! Thanks so much for helping out. Would you happen to know what might be causing https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718545/printing-pdf-using-lp-results-in-toner-not-adhering-to-paper?

Answer (score 1):

[Enable cups web interface](https://help.gettimely.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360061129574-How-to-enable-CUPs-web-interface) to edit the cups.conf file in an easy way:

- Open the terminal
- Paste in `cupsctl WebInterface=yes` and press enter

Go to the Cups web page at http://localhost:631/printers/ and see your installed printers.

- In the top menu click 'Administration'
- On the right you find a button 'Edit Configuration File'
- There you can add the information to delete the history files. Mine looks like this (the 1800 makes the deamon wait for half an hour before deleting):

  ```
  PreserveJobFiles 1800
  PreserveJobHistory 1800
  ```
- Click "Save Changes" and enter username/password of an admin user when prompted.

For more information see https://www.cups.org/doc/man-cupsd.conf.html

Answer (score 0):

From [the blog of the OP](https://sunknudsen.com/privacy-guides/how-to-disable-cups-printer-job-history-on-macos):

```
echo "PreserveJobHistory Off" | sudo tee -a /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist
```

Unfortunately, `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` sometimes gets overwritten during a macOS update. I have

```
grep -qe '^PreserveJobHistory Off$' /etc/cups/cupsd.conf || echo 'WARNING: CUPS history ENABLED'
```

in the startup file of the shell I use to warn me if this happens.